# Problem with numpy.prod (gives negative numbers multiplying positive numbers)

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain to me, why this happens -

`np.prod(np.arange(1,34))>0` 
is true but
`np.prod(np.arange(1,32))>0`
is false
???

I tried multiplying the first 100 numbers with
`np.prod(np.arange(1,100))`

This gave me 0, so I tried finding the problem, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with this, the problem is overflow.

A Python int won't overflow, but numpy uses types like int32 and int64 which have limits on values that they can hold.

If you approach the limit that the numpy variable can hold you risk an invalid result that may look ok, an apparent invalid result, or a zero.

If you need values like this, you can't use numpy. Just use the regular Python int.

Here's the doc link which discusses this more: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors

Comment: Now everything makes sense. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

as explained by Chase LP , you can solve the issue by force typecasting using astype() method or just straight up use math.factorial if that is what you want

```
np.prod(np.arange(1,100).astype(float))>0
np.math.factorial(100)>0
```